# C# return index of array where value matches an arbitrary string

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

I need to find the index of an item in an array of strings where that item's value matches a certain pattern.

Example array & values:

```
string[] stringArray = { "roleName","UserID=000000","OtherID=11111" }
```

I need to get the index of the item whose value begins with "UserID=".  I know I could iterate through the array and match each value to a regex, but that just sounds slow and messy.  I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
int indexIneed = Array.IndexOf(stringArray,"\bUserID=");
```

But I've never really had to mess with regular expressions before, so I fumbling around like a toddler.  Is there I way I can accomplish what I'm tring to do in O(n) or am I going to have to resort to iteration?

Comment: What's wrong with the simple iteration? Why do you consider it "slow and messy"? It is O(n) in fact, if you do not take into account the regex matching cost.

Comment: `IndexOf` Iterates the array and is O(n).

Comment: @DixonD and Magnus  You're both absolutely right.  For some reason I was thinking it would be O(n<sup>2</sup>).  Deadlines have me jumping to conclusions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03y7c6xy(v=vs.110).aspx) will give you what you want:

```
int indexIneed = Array.FindIndex(stringArray,s => s.StartsWith("UserID="));
```

Comment: completely forgot about that. +1 :)

Comment: anyway, it is the same iteration, just one-liner. the same can be done with LINQ also

Comment: @DixonD not without creating unnecessary objects